# Codeigniter session is not working on PHP 7

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am using **codeigniter version 3.0.6** on **PHP 5.6** and it works fine. but when I run same project on **PHP 7.1** , codeigniter session is not working. I set session like below

```
$login_session = $this->session->set_userdata("user_session",$session_data);
```

when I print  **$login_session**  it is blank on PHP 7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718961/codeigniter-3-session-not-working-with-php-7-1-4

Comment: Have you checked the Bug issue?  https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4830

Comment: Here is the Solution check if it works: http://www.jianshu.com/p/4bf22c8af19d

Comment: its chinese dude

Comment: upgrade to 3.1.5

Comment: Updating system folder from CI 3.1.5 solved issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 43):

Recently I've faced the same problem by upgrading my php version from 5.6 to 7.1
My development environment is XAMPP (Apache + MariaDB) using php7.1.4

Please follow the below steps:

1) Go to system/libraries/Session/Session.php

2) Comment session_start() by adding //.

3) Go down to line around 312-315 where it says Security is king, and comment out the following lines:

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 4);
```

4) Then go to your main index.php ( the root index.php )

5) Add session_start() at the top once.

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks bro! It worked. Hope this will not break any security right?

Comment: WC. no it'll not break any security issue.

Comment: You saved my day, except I spend 5 hours to find it, thank you man thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a good answer. It'll work, but the issue is the version of Codeigniter used. Check @Siddesh answer.

Comment: I spend almost 6hour on this issues, at last, it solved thanks @Shafiq Brother

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Step 1, 2 and 5 is working for me fine. I don't need to follow other steps.
I am using php7.4 and CI 3.1.9

Answer (score 38):

Session id is different in php 7.1 and not pass the regex checking.

A simple fix:
In system/libraries/Session/Session.php arround line 133

```
OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
```

remove '{40}$'

```
OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
```

The problem is that the session id is deleted from cookie because the regex mismatch. So the session id always renew.

This can fix the regular expression and prevent it run the line 
"unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);"

It totally works for me !

FYI. Find this after I fix it myself.
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4830

Comment: best solution if you dont want to update codeigniter or any other thing

Comment: this is best solution than editing 2 files like the top answer

Comment: This solution is simply perfect but I need to know that, will it lead to any security issues?

Comment: It seems will not lead to security issues, because it only remove length checking.If the session id mismatch, it still not pass the checking

Answer (score 12):

I propose the following steps:

1. Go to https://www.codeigniter.com, download the latest 3.x.x version of the framework and unzip it.
2. Make a copy of the system folder in the existing app, save it somewhere else then delete the one in your app folder.
3. Take a copy of the system folder you just downloaded and place where you deleted the last one from.
4. Finish!

This solves the problem seamlessly, it saves you time as well as the potential risk of messing your app up.

Comment: this is the solution to this problem should be the top answer

Answer (score 10):

I found that the issue is with some earlier version of Codeigniter 3 and this is a bug already reported in their website. The bug has been fixed and in the latest version of Codeigniter 3 this issue doesn't happen.

If you are already in a faulty version cogeinter consider replacing system folder with latest version's one.

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718961/codeigniter-3-session-not-working-with-php-7-1-4)

Comment: This is copied answer and given in above thread. why are you copying this instead giving the URL?

Comment: Because the website's article could be not longer available.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have set the session save path

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/session/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Set the folder permission 0700

Autoload session if you want

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

How to set the session

```
$session = array('islogged' => true, 'user_id' => '1');

$this->session->set_userdata($session);
```

Get the user data one set examples

```
echo $this->session->userdata('user_id');

if (!$this->session->userdata('islogged')) {
     redirect('logout');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you just need to go inside `application/config/config.php` this file and set session path

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
```

that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem and wasted a whole day.
Here is simple solution.

Just download [CodeIgniter 3.1.11](https://codeigniter.com/download) version and copy the system folder and replace the system folder with your old system folder

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade Codeigniter to latest version.
Issue will resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from your PHP version, PHP 7.1 is not really stable, and has a lot of issues with sessions. Change your PHP version to 7.0 and sessions will automatically start working.

Comment: Kindly explain the down voting

Comment: I had recently switched from php5.6 to php7.1. Session immediately stopped working. This suggestion is the only thing that worked for me. Reinstalling codeigniter core and checking my session configs didn't help. However I have several versions of PHP available and when I switched from 7.1 to 7.0 my sessions worked again.