# Session getting lost on regenerating session id in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter application where the session is set when a user logs in and is shown the user dashboard with somewhat like the code below:

```
public function checkLogin()
{
    $username = $this->input->post("username");
    $password = $this->input->post("password");

    $userId = $this->ModelLogin->checkLogin($username, $password);

    if ($userId) {
        $session_data = array(
            'is_logged_in' => true,
            'userId' => $userId,
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        redirect("/user/dashboard");
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', "Incorrect username/password");
    }
}
```

Now I am to fix a *Session Fixation* issue by regenerating the Session ID before authenticating the user. When I include the `session_regenerate_id()` or even the codeigniter specific `$this->session->sess_regenerate()` function, it works within this function but as soon as it is redirected to the `/user/dashboard` the session data gets blank.

I am adding the regenerate line just before the `$this->session->set_userdata($session_data);`. The above code works perfectly without the regenerate.

Additionally, I am using the **database** session driver. When I switch to the files driver, even the regenerate logic works perfectly. It's just something with the database driver (I feel) is causing this issue.

Comment: What is the php and codeigniter version?

Comment: If you are not using latest CI on PHP7, maybe you can fix the session bug like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56355732/3929170

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this after days of trial and error.

This was present in Codeigniter 3.0.x that too on PHP 7.x (which was what my application was running on)

After extensive search, I stumbled upon a Codeigniter changelog that mentioned a regression bug fix in some later versions (3.0.x) of Codeigniter and that's when I started scanning through the changes in the Codeigniter session library and the database driver where I found this snippet:

```
// PHP7 will reuse the same SessionHandler object after
// ID regeneration, so we need to explicitly set this to
// FALSE instead of relying on the default ...
    $this->_row_exists = FALSE;
```

Just when I brought this only line change into my existing codeigniter system, the problem was solved instantly!