# PHP Codeigniter Session error: Message: session_cache_limiter(): Cannot change cache limiter when session is active

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

php -v:7.3.11

codeigniter  -v:3.0.3

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: session_cache_limiter(): Cannot change cache limiter when session is active

Filename: core/MY_Controller.php

Line Number: 24

Backtrace:

File: G:\xamp\htdocs\sales_pro\a\site\application\core\MY_Controller.php
Line: 24
Function: session_cache_limiter

File: G:\xamp\htdocs\sales_pro\a\site\application\controllers\admin\Login.php
Line: 16
Function: __construct

File: G:\xamp\htdocs\sales_pro\a\site\index.php
Line: 309
Function: require_once
```

I tried commenting out the following lines in system/libraries/session/session.php
but not working

```
session_start()
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', 1);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_function', 1);
ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 4);
```

I also tried

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
 }
```

Comment: Already asked some where [ Click me to see solutions ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756370/codeigniter-session-is-not-working-on-php-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

swithched codeigniter version to 3.1... And the issue solved