# Codeigniter HMVC Login just keeps reloading

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I've been asked to take over a site by a client who; she lost touch with their developer. Looks like CI HMVC is running on the site but I'm new to it. My problem is when you log in with correct user credentials the screen just reloads. Apparently it stopped working once the website host upgraded to PHP 7.x

It's 7.3 now but the lowest they can go to is 7.1. The last time code was updated was 2015 May.

Opening config files and this is what I see

```
 * Modular Extensions - HMVC
 *
 * Adapted from the CodeIgniter Core Classes
 * @link    http://codeigniter.com
 *
 * Description:
 * This library extends the CodeIgniter CI_Config class
 * and adds features allowing use of modules and the HMVC design pattern.
 *
 * Install this file as application/third_party/MX/Config.php
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2015 Wiredesignz
 * @version     5.5
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to begin troubleshooting what the problem is as I'm totally listing?

I've also tried updating the PHP config to display errors and still no luck as to what might be the issue. And no errors are returned on the screen. When I purposefully use the wrong password I get an invalid username or password message. Which tells me the DB connection and lookup is working. I'm just stumped as to why I can't progress past the login screen

Please advise

Andrew

Comment: check the session data  echo '<pre>'; $this->session->all_userdata(); then check the controller redirect anthing occurs on the controller which redirects after login

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear with your question but what I could understand that Your codeigniter application redirects to login page again and again if you logged in with right credentials.
I supposed that you are running your application at difference version of PHP that's not supported by your application.

suppose your application support upto 5.6 version and you are running your application at 7.0 version.

so just change your server version(5.5) that will compatible to your app.

Comment: Is there anyway to rather make the app compatible to PHP 7 as the host wont downgrade unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756370/codeigniter-session-is-not-working-on-php-7
try mentioned answers in above link.